In power pivot, is it possible to divide the aggregated results of one row by another within a pivot table?
I have a single table loaded into power pivot in Excel that reports charges, expected revenue (Expected Rev), and volume quantity (VolQty) in a single field (Cat 1). Using this information, I want to calculate the average charge per quantity and the average expected revenue per quantity. I can do this with a simple formula outside of the pivot table in Excel (i.e., Charges / VolQty). However, I'd rather do this calculation within the pivot table.
Data with Formula Calculations



Rank
Cat 1
Sum of OR Case
Average




1
Charges
2,538,795,232
44,744


2
Expected Rev
911,462,251
16,064


4
VolQty
56,741
1



I've tried to do the calculation within the pivot table in three different ways:
1st attempt
In the Values section of the PivotTables Fields window, I changed Sum of OR Case to Average of OR Case. Unfortunately, the results are incorrect.



Rank
Cat 1
Sum of OR Case
Average




1
Charges
2,538,795,232
14,885


2
Expected Rev
911,462,251
5,344


4
VolQty
56,741
0



2nd attempt
In the Values section of the PivotTables Fields window, I reverted to Sum of OR Case but then adjusted settings in the Value field settings option (Show Values As > % Of > Base field = Cat 1 and Base item = VolQty). This time, I just get an #N/A error message in the Charges and Expected Rev rows.



Rank
Cat 1
Sum of OR Case
Average




1
Charges
2,538,795,232
#N/A


2
Expected Rev
911,462,251
#N/A


4
VolQty
56,741
100%



3rd attempt
I tried to create a DAX measure within power pivot. Here's the formula: SUMX(DISTINCT(Table[Expense Category]),[Sum of OR Case])/CALCULATE(SUM([OR Case]),Table[Expense Category]="VolQty"). Similar to the prior attempt, I get an error message... this time #NUM!.



Rank
Cat 1
Sum of OR Case
Average




1
Charges
2,538,795,232
#NUM!


2
Expected Rev
911,462,251
#NUM!


4
VolQty
56,741
1



Note that the data lives in the power pivot data model so calculated fields in a normal pivot table aren't an option.

It's simple to do, but you need to stop thinking in terms of pivot table fields, and instead think in terms of DAX measures.
Instead of "Sum of OR Case", create a DAX measure (note: I am guessing your data table and field names):
Total OR Cases = SUM( Table[OR Case] )

Then, create a second measure:
Volume Cases =
CALCULATE (
    [Total OR Cases],
    ALL ( Table ),
    Table[Expense Category] = "VolQty"
)

Finally, the desired result measure:
Average Cases = DIVIDE( [Total OR Cases], [Volume Cases])

Result:


Thanks RADO. I've followed your solution. In the pivot table, now the only row that shows up is VolQty and Grand Total, the Charges and Expected Rev rows don't show up. What other information can I provide?

One more thing to add. The data for the numerator and denominator are in the same column.

I've updated the answer, try it.

Thank you, I'll give it a try and report back on Monday

RADO, that worked! But now I've run into a new issue. If I add additional categories into the rows (e.g., volume category) or columns (e.g., source of charges, called payer in the table), the calculated averages are incorrect. But without those extra rows/ columns, the totals are correct. Is there a way to fix this new issue?

Based on what I'm reading, shadow filter contexts with the ALLSELECTED function may be the answer. But that's are far as I've gotten.
